# Combine two columns into one in Julia DataFrames

Tags: dataframe, join, merge, julia, ijulia-notebook

I need some help due to my research about that topic was not satisfying.
I hope you guys can help me out.
Lets say we have a DataFrame like:

```
df = DataFrame(A = 1:10, B = 11:20, C = rand(10))
```

But now I want to join "A" and "B" into one single column so it goes from 1 to 20. How do I do that...? :/

Thanks for our help!

Comment: and what do you want to happen to column `:C`? Or more generally - what output would you expect?

Comment: :C could go on to rand(20) it does not matter.

Answer (score 0):

Given how I understood what you need do:

```
DataFrame(AB=[df.A; df.B], C=rand(20))
```

but maybe you need something else. In such a case please comment.